# how should I 301 redirect https address to http address?

Tags: ssl, .htaccess, redirect, https

I have recently moved my website to a new domain.

The previous domain had SSL installed and it was https://example.com. My new domain is http://newexample.com and It doesn't have SSL on it. I used google webmaster tools to change the address of my website but it can't verify 301 redirect.

How can I 301 redirect https://example.com to http://newexample.com using .htaccess?

Comment: Don't you want to send `https://example.com/` to `http://newexample.com/`?

Comment: yeah the editor made a mistake I edited it again !

Comment: I was the editor, and I didn't make a mistake, I just fixed your formatting a bit. http://serverfault.com/posts/709162/revisions Thank you for clarifying though.

Comment: sry then the problem was on my side . now it's ok . Please answer the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://newexample.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: where is https in this line ? RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]

Comment: @rko4all123 The HTTPS requirement is the line above that. There are two conditions here - HTTPS must be on, and the hostname must be example.com, for the redirect to occur.

Comment: thanks ! it works ! now I can change my address in google webmaster tools . you are awesome .